# A word to describe all things in the list have to match

Tags: word-request

I was recently correcting a document, which listed specific requirements, all of which must be met. The original author wrote:

- *Condition A*, AND
- *Condition B*, AND
- *Condition C*

I've removed the "AND" from the document and now wish to inform the author that the requirements in the document are "and-chained" in nature. Obviously, "and-chained" isn't a real word in the English language. Is there a word for this?

And example sentence:

> You don't need to specify "AND" for every requirement; requirements are ____ by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is not very clear, but I guess you are looking for the word **mandatory** (as opposed to **optional**).

> You don't need to specify "AND" for every requirement; ***all*** requirements are **mandatory** by default.